# Format HUGE JSON file

Tags: json, text

I have a huge unformatted JSON file - size is around 2.5G. Is there any tool or way to write script that can help me to format this file into well-readable indented format? I have PC with Intel Core i7 and 16GB memory, so it is more-less that elevated hardware requirement should not be an issue.

Comment: Are you really wanting to human read a 2.5GB json file, that could be 3-4GB when formatted ?

Comment: yes, I was ok with that.

Comment: simple solution [how to format big json file in effective way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875218/best-way-to-format-large-json-file-30-mb)

Comment: Nowadays probably just jq will work

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). I haven't tried it with such a large file, but Webstorm is able to handle really big files. There is a 30 day trial version, so you may give it a try.

Once you've opened the file in Webstorm click `Code`-> `Reformat Code`.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use Jackson Streaming API. Since it is streaming it will read token by token of your JSON file and will not consume too much memory.

An example of streaming API can be found on this [link](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-json-streaming.jsp).

Answer (score -2):

There is an online tool - https://conversiontools.io/convert/format-json which is able to format JSON files of up to 100 GB.

But there are limits for free usage - at the moment of writing it's only possible to convert files (for free) up to 20MB.