# VSCode: File is too large for tokenization / formatting

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, formatting, filesize

I have an 800kb *.json file all condensed into one line.

The built-in JSON formatter seems to refuse to format and tokenize the file and after searching for a while I haven't found any solutions. How can I do this?

Comment: according to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63639) there's a 20k char limit for that functionality to work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I needed to format ~90MB json file. Initially Vscode was stubborn, but I found a workaround.

Open JSON file and 'save as' it under any name. Somehow this triggers something and it then becomes recognised as JSON file. Then you can use 'Format Document'.

Beawere, first time it crashed Vscode because process was suspended. Had to close and start over, just this time I set the priority on Vscode process to high and then it ran fast and quite smoothly.

My PC has 24GB ram, Vscode was using about 7.

Comment: MS needs to fix this bug on priority 

Comment: Did not work on 1.84.0, on a macOS 12.7

Comment: I had ~160MB JSON file and this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have JSON extension installed in VS Code.

You need to increase the maximum number of outline symbols and folding regions computed.

Go to Settings -> input `json.maxItemsComputed` in the search bar -> increase the number from 5000 to any number you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19875307/7344164), you can use a simple python command to format large JSON files

```
cat ugly.json | python -m json.tool > pretty.json
```